# Does zone damage count as a hit with a power?

Tags: dnd-4e

In this case I am talking about a specific scenario involving the following feat and power combo.

I have a level 9 Invoker who has [Mark of Storm](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=1397):

> Mark of Storm [Dragonmark]
>
> **Benefit**: Whenever you hit an enemy with a thunder or lightning power, you can slide that enemy 1 square.

I am considering taking the L9 Invoker Daily, [Herald of the Storm Unleashed](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=7188), which has the following:

> **Effect**: The burst creates a zone of lightning and thunder that lasts until the end of your next turn. Any creature that begins its turn within the zone takes 5 lightning damage. Any creature that leaves the zone takes 5 thunder damage. As a move action, you can move the zone 5 squares.

Would creatures starting in or leaving the zone be subject to the slide granted by Mark of Storm?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No, creatures starting in or leaving the zone are not subject to the slide granted by Mark of Storm**

From the Players Handbook p276 and the [DDI Compendium](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=128) description of **Hit**

> If the attack roll is higher than or equal to the defense score, the attack hits...

And further rulings on the non-hitting-ness of non-attack roll powers such as the *Heroes of the Fallen Lands* update to Magic Missile (see [Does the New Magic Missile Trigger "On Hit" Powers or Effects?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/3104/does-the-new-magic-missile-trigger-on-hit-powers-or-effects)), since the damage from starting a turn in a zone has no associated attack roll, there is no hit off of which mark of storm can trigger.

Answer (score 2):

### No

You only get the benefit from powers that trigger on a hit when you successfully roll to hit.

The DMG defines Hit on page 276 under Attack Results.